# AS3: Casting to Vector

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

I am trying to create a vector from unknown class, but it fails, any ideas about how to do it?

This is what i tried:

```
var vector:Vector = new Vector(); // throw exception

function base():void{
var vector:Vector.<String> = createVector(String);// throw classCastException
}

function createVector(cls:Class):*{
     var array:Array = new Array();
     for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
         var element:cls = new cls();
          array.push(element);
     }

     return Vector(array);
}
```

Comment: Create vector for object : var vec:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>;

Comment: This is a compiler error

Comment: this one can be compiled for sure . Anyway , I think You missmatch sens of using Vector if You like to store different types of objects .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Patrick answer I found a working solution.

Check it out:

```
function createVector(cls:Class):*{
        var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(cls);
        var vectorClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("__AS3__.vec::Vector.<"+className+">") as Class;

        var vector:* = new vectorClass(10);        
        for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
            var element:MyClass = new cls(); // may be Object or Object extends cls
            vector[i] = element;
        }

        return vector;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) is expecting a parameter type so you can't do this like you want, but using [getQualifiedClassName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29) to get class info you can construct a string that will enable you to call the Vector. constructor using [getDefinitionByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29) :

Ex.

```
// get class parameter name
var className:String=getQualifiedClassName(String);

// get the Vector class object for the given class
var o:Object=getDefinitionByName("__AS3__.vec::Vector<"+className+">");

// call the constructor
var v:*=o.prototype.constructor(["hello", "world"]);
```

So your function can be written as:

```
    public function createVector(cls:Class):*{
        var cn:String = getQualifiedClassName(cls);
        var o:Object = getDefinitionByName("__AS3__.vec::Vector.<"+cn+">");
        var array:Array = [];
        for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
            var element:* = new cls();
            array.push(element);
        }
        return o.prototype.constructor(array);
    }
```

live example at wonderfl:
http://wonderfl.net/c/pkjs

Comment: Strange because you have just a live working example on wonderfl. What is the error you had ?
You can create the vector and filling it after like you did there is no pb, i just tried to stick to your initialization part using an Array.

Comment: the o.prototype.constructor(array) cost exception, and creating new array is not necessary